# Change projection system .tif file

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have a list of .tif files which have the wrong projection system (NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N). However, I want to have those files in (WGS_1984). I want to do this by a script that can transform tif files from one projection system to another. I have found many scripts online, but none seem to work for me. anyone a script or idea?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that none worked for you? What have youtried so far? and when you say that the images have the wrong projection, do you mean that the wrong projection nameis present, or that they are currently in UTM_13N and want to project to WGS_84?

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified much information, but it sounds like you are trying to do this in batch fashion, outside of any GIS type applications.

You can use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) to do raster reprojection.
You didn't mention what OS you are running, so I can't provide specific help for the setup of GDAL and such, but it's generally pretty easy for Windows and Linux.

After you have it installed you can use `gdalwarp` to convert from UTM to WGS84:

`gdalwarp -t_srs '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' <input_name>.tif <output_name>.tif`

If the file *is* in WGS84 already, but its tagged as UTM then you can do the below (this just assigns a different system, no reprojection):

`gdal_translate -a_srs '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs' <input_name>.tif <output_name>.tif`